# Showing 2 notions are equivalent

Tags: algebraic-geometry, proof-writing, category-theory

When an exercise asks you to show 2 notions are equivalent, what is it really asking you to do?

For example in Hartshorne chapter 2 exercise 2.7 he asks us to show that given a scheme $(X, O_X)$ and a field $K$ and for $x \in X$ denoting by $k(x)$ the field $O_x/m_x$ where $O_x$ is the stalk of the sheaf $O_X$ at $x$, that to give a morphism of $Spec K$ to $X$ is equivalent to giving a point $x \in X$ and an inclusion $k(x) \rightarrow K$.

The reason I ask is that I've seen solutions to questions like these which (in the context of my  example for clarity's sake) given a morphism will show that you can create a point and the inclusion map, and conversely given the point and map show you can create the morphism and just do that.

However I remember a lecturer giving me a question like this and in his solution he also shows that going from one notion to the other then back again results in the original thing (and does this both ways).

This extra bit of work seems to make sense if we are trying to establish perhaps a bijection between the sets of the 2 notions in the question but I am unsure if that is what these questions are asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's phrase this more precisely: the general form of such questions is 'given a mathematical object $X$, specifying a structure $\sigma_1$ on $X$ of one kind is equivalent to specifying a structure $\sigma_2$ on $X$ of another kind'. Let $S_1$ be the set of structures on $X$ of the first kind and let $S_2$ be the set of structures on $X$ of the second kind.

If specifying an $S_1$-structure on $X$ is to be equivalent to specifying an $S_2$-structure on $X$, then:

- Each $\sigma_1 \in S_1$ can be obtained by specifying some $\sigma_2 \in S_2$ and applying some procedure to $\sigma_2$, which means that you have an injective function $S_1 \to S_2$ (which sends $\sigma_1$ to some choice of $\sigma_2$ which determines it); and
- Each $\sigma_2 \in S_2$ can be obtained by specifying some $\sigma_1 \in S_1$ and applying some procedure to $\sigma_1$, which means that you have an injective function $S_2 \to S_1$.

I see no reason in general why these functions should be mutually inverse (thereby establishing a bijection), but if they are, then that's a bonus! But if they're not mutually inverse, then they'd better be injective. In any case, the [Cantor–Schröder–Bernstein theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%E2%80%93Bernstein_theorem) then implies that a bijection $S_1 \to S_2$ exists, even if you haven't explicitly defined it.

In more practical terms, this amounts to saying that each $S_1$-structure gives rise to at most one $S_2$-structure, and vice versa, but the procedures for going in each direction might be different (and, in particular, might not be mutually inverse).

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer, this is what I had at first though was going on. However compared to what Najib wrote it seems to me that his answer includes something more- he requires more structure in his mapping between the 2 sets $S_1$ and $S_2$ in the fact that it must be a bijection, it must commute with morphisms and we need a map of morphsims too.

I am also confused as to why my lecturer found it necessary to then add in that extra bit of work if it was not necessary as you say.

I did ask him about this when he gave out the exercise but I didn't really understand his reply

Comment: and he gave me the following "stupid example" as to why just exhibiting the 2 maps is not enough: "Every $\mathbb C [x]$-module is a $\mathbb C$ module and so a vector space over $\mathbb C$. While every vector space over $\mathbb C$ can be turned into a  $\mathbb C [x]$-module by setting multiplication by $x$ to be 0. But evidently the 2 structures are not equivalent."

I am unsure if the maps given in that example are actually injections and as to what my lecturer meant by " evidently the 2 structures are not equivalent" but perhaps you could explain this too?

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that when I asked my lecturer about this, the original question was about showing that for a fixed ring $R$ and abelian group $V$ that the structure of a left $R$-module on $V$ is equivalent to a ring homomorphism from $R \rightarrow End(V)$, which to me seems slightly different than his "stupid example" I gave above.

Comment: @Fromage: Your lecturer's $\mathbb{C}$-module doesn't work, since "setting multiplication by $x$ to be $0$" doesn't give you an injective map. There is something to be said for obtaining a *categorical equivalence* between categories of structures (like in Najib's answer), but typically, when someone says "specifying this structure is the same as specifying that structure", all they're doing is talking about the *objects* and not talking about the *morphisms*. (continued...)

Comment: If you want to talk about an equivalence of categories, then there has to be a notion of morphism of "objects with $S_1$-structure" and a notion of morphism of "objects with $S_2$-structure". If you have access to such morphisms, and they do indeed form a category, then obtaining a categorical equivalence is a much nicer thing to have, than simply saying that "putting an $S_1$-structure on $X$ is the same as putting an $S_2$-structure on $X$". (Hopefully my comments serve to clarify rather than confuse...)

Comment: Alright mate, cheers for your replies. Yeah I understand what your talking about and essentially what you and Najib wrote were my 2 understandings of the question but since there are these 2 interpretations I was unsure which one to follow.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to phrase that in the language of categories. Consider the category $\mathsf{Sch}$ of schemes, the category $\mathsf{Set}$ of sets, and the category $\mathsf{Fld}$ of fields. You have two functors<sup>*</sup> $\mathsf{Sch} \to \mathsf{Set}$, given by:
$$\begin{align}
F : X & \mapsto \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathsf{Sch}}(\operatorname{Spec} K, X) \\
G : X & \mapsto \{ (x, i) \mid x \in X, i \in \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathsf{Fld}}(k(x), K)
\end{align}$$

what Hartshorne is asking you to do is to prove that there two functors are naturally isomorphic, i.e. finding an isomorphism (a bijection) $\eta_X : F(X) \to G(X)$ which commutes with all natural maps. Pretty much any problem of the form you are describing can be rephrased this way.

(What your lecturer did was describing $\eta : F \to G$ but also the inverse natural isomorphism $\theta : G \to F$, and proving that $\eta \circ \theta = \operatorname{id}$ and $\theta \circ \eta = \operatorname{id}$. Of course strictly speaking you don't need to do that, but what better way to prove that something is an isomorphism than to explicitly describe its inverse isomorphism?)

---

<sup>*</sup> Strictly speaking I'm only describing what the functors do on objects. You must also describe what it does on morphisms, i.e. if $f : X \to Y$ is a morphism of schemes, what's the induced function $F(X) \to F(Y)$ (resp. $G(X) \to G(Y)$)? I leave that as an exercise.

Comment: Thanks alot for your answer, I was in particular looking for an answer which used some Category theory.
However if you look at Clive's answer, to me yours says something more than his- he just says that you need to exhibit 2 injective functions from the sets of both the structures into each other. Whilst yours says that you have to have this mapping, but it also needs to be bijective (he says this comes from the CBS theorem, but there's no reason for the 2 injections to be inverses) and also that the bijection commutes with the morphisms, and we also need the bijection on morphsims too.

Comment: Are what you and Clive have written the same, and if not why not?